# Debugging a Chrome Extension right withthin the Editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-chrome-extension

I come from the world of iOS dev, here you simply set breakpoints in the editor and test the app in simulator.

In iOS, it's very simple: https://youtu.be/mgspBMsWlS4?t=140
2:20 - 2:40 -- it's done!

How do you do similar debugging in VSCode for Chrome extensions?